# The Variable {{ siteUrl }} Produces Two /es/es/ On Multisite

Tags: localization, multi-site, language, siteurl

I'm getting example.com/es/es for my Spanish site instead of the expected example.com/es when using the {{ siteUrl }} variable.

The primary site is producing the expected example.com/

Any idea of how I did that incorrectly?

Comment: What is the `Base URL` setting set to for this particular site?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, though I'm confused on why some of it was working fine... Maybe if it broke more fully I would have found it easier, haha.

Mats was right, it was the Base URL in the Sites area of the admin control panel. I had entered @web/es thinking that I want it to be the root of the primary site, but that wasn't correct, I needed to just put @web/ because I already told it that it lived at /es through the index.php of that site folder.

Comment: @jonsuther would you mind adding your solution as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, though I'm confused on why some of it was working fine... Maybe if it broke more fully I would have found it easier, haha. Mats was right, it was the Base URL in the Sites area of the admin control panel. I had entered @web/es thinking that I want it to be the root of the primary site, but that wasn't correct, I needed to just put @web/ because I already told it that it lived at /es through the index.php of that site folder.